# Как в VS Code отключить выделение значения атрибута?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Видео-вопрос:** https://youtu.be/Q5RQFG_Nc1U

В программе VS Code установлено расширение, подставляющее в HTML классы из CSS.
Но если для тега ввести атрибут "class" с помощью автоматической подстановки (нажатием Tab), значение этого атрибута почему-то автоматически выделяется и расширение, которое должно подставлять значения не работает.

Чтобы оно заработало, нужно снять выделение нажатием Esc.

**Вопрос:** можно ли как-то отключить это выделение значения атрибута, чтобы автоподстановка работала всегда?
Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут дело не в настройках, а в расширении. Лучше всего спросить у автора - найдите его github-репозиторий и создайте issue.

Comment: Нет, дело в настройках Intellisense в программе VS Code, а не в расширении

Comment: Когда вы табом автодополняете аттрибут, срабатывает функционал [сниппетов](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). Содержимое аттрибутов это обычные строки, они ожидают что именно вы их будете заполнять. Это не какие-то внешние объекты и intellisense к ним отношения не имеет. Но ваш плагин делает их таковыми, по этому плагин и должен заботиться о подобных проблемах.

Comment: Чтобы не снимать выделение эскейпом, можно ctrl+пробел нажать.

Comment: **> "Но ваш плагин делает их таковыми, по этому плагин и должен заботиться о подобных проблемах"**

Я считаю, что не в плагине дело, потому что при установке чистого VS Code (вообще без плагинов) эта проблема остаётся.
P.S. Спасибо за подсказку насчет Ctrl+Space. Хотя это и не идеальное решение.

Comment: Тут дело не в настройках, а в расширении. Лучше всего спросить у автора - найдите его github-репозиторий и создайте issue

Answer (score 3):

В настройках убрать галочку с:
Editor › Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это не отключит выделение, но включит автодополнение.

Comment: Хоть что-то. Спасибо