# Как в настройках Visual Studio Code убрать автоматическое выделение?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я использую автодополнение "if/else" для Python (но язык не важен, т. к. нижеописанная проблема возникает во всех языках).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получаю такую конструкцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я хочу вставить с помощью автодополнения имя переменной "chislo", меню автодополнения не открывается, т. к. "condition", "pass" и "pass" выделены серым цветом. Насколько я понял, такой вид выделения сделали для того, чтобы было удобно перемещаться по этим командам с помощью клавиши "Tab". Но, из-за этого выделения я не могу пользоваться автодополнением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если просто написать "if", не используя автодополнение, то при вводе "c" (первой буквы имени переменной "chislo") меню автодополнения открывается нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в настройках убрать это автоматическое выделение?

Comment: Предположу, что это связано с тем, что вы не начинаете писать новое слово (через пробел, например), а как бы исправляете старое. Попробуйте после стирания слова ``condition`` нажать комбинацию клавиш, которая выводит подсказку (у меня это ``ctrl + space``)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001506/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-vs-code-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что вы делаете называется snippet.

Вы можете создать свой собственный snippet и определить его как захотите. Т.е. вы можете создать похожий шаблон if/else и добавить, например, пустые строки вместо `condition` и `pass`. Думаю, что должно получится.

Вот например есть вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode)